# Erro de constraint ao tentar persistir com cascade

Tags: java, jpa

Bom dia, estou com o seguinte problema

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: não é possível inserir NULL em ("XXGOVC"."ASSINATURA"."ID_DIRETRIZ")
```

E aqui é o mapeamento das minhas entidades...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DIRETRIZ")
public class Diretriz {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID_DIRETRIZ", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(generator="ID_DIRETRIZ_SEQ", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="ID_DIRETRIZ_SEQ", name="ID_DIRETRIZ_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
private Long idDiretriz;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "diretriz", orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<Assinatura> assinaturas;
```

e...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSINATURA")
public class Assinatura{    

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_ASSINATURA", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="ID_ASSINATURA_SEQ", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="ID_ASSINATURA_SEQ", name="ID_ASSINATURA_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    private Long idAssinatura;      


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DIRETRIZ")
    private Diretriz diretriz;
```

já pesquisei e li a documentação e aparentemente os mapeamentos estão todos corretos, será que alguém pode me dizer se esta tudo correto, se estou esquecendo de algo... desde já agradeço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode mostrar o codigo de quando você está tentando inserir?
Porque mesmo estando tudo certo com o mapeamento, no momento do insert, possivelmente voce não está inserido a referencia de um para o outro. Exemplo:

```
Assinatura a = new Assinatura();
a.setDiretriz(objetoDiretriz);
...
objetoDiretriz.getAssinaturas().add(a);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, realmente não sabia que era necessário fazer isso, mesmo assim, fiz conforme falou e não deu certo

Comment: Cara era realmente isso, da primeira vez não deu porque eu ainda tinha mais uma lista que não estava fazendo isso... vlw mesmo

Comment: Saquei...valeuuu